# Android Started Service, Handler Thread with Location Services Api

Tags: android, android-location, android-handler

In my app scenario, I want to keep `Started Service` throughout the life of my app. In this service, I have to use `FusedLocationProviderClient` with `LocationServices api` to request location updates (for exactly, in `onStartCommand` method). Whenever the new "**location update**" received, the updated location will be saved into the `PreferenceManager`.

When the user logouts from the app, I will stop this `Started Service`.

**Do I need to handle this location update logic in new `HandlerThread` (you know, because Started Service runs on Main Thread)?**

From my opinion, since the `FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates` (from LocationServices Api) method is non-blocking call and based on Asynchronous programming model, I think `HandlerThread` will not be needed in my scenario.

**P.S.** I took the references from [GoogleSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService). In that sample, they demonstrate the Bound Service which is also started (will not be ended when not client bound). They also don't implement the actual logic for HandlerThread to get the location updates.

Comment: no `HandlerThread` needed in that case - provided you are just saving the update in local storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you do when a "new location" event fires.

Do you do heavy processing or networks calls? -> separate thread. Do you do simple stuff that only takes a couple ms? -> doesn't really matter which of these threads you run it on.

Comment: I just save the location information in PreferenceManager when "new location" event fires.

Comment: @Steve.NayLinAung that's pretty light weight. Not worth setting up a handlerthread for

Comment: Thanks, ticked the answer.